# How do Wildfire + Burn It! interact?

Tags: spells, feats, pathfinder-2e, stacking

[Burn It!](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=38) increases fire damage:

> Your spells and alchemical items that deal fire damage gain a status bonus to damage equal to half the spell's level or one-quarter the item's level (minimum 1).

[Wildfire](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1059) does fire damage *per square*:

> A creature that moves on the ground through the area takes 1 fire damage **for every square of that area it moves into**.

Is the combined damage increase per square?

Comment: It's worth noting that Burn it! is not the only Status bonus to damage. Bards can provide a Status bonus to all damage, not just fire, with Inspire Courage. Yes, Burn it! rapidly outpaces other bonuses, but the basis is there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### There is no reason these don't stack

Burn It! works on spells that deal fire damage and Wildfire is a spell that deals fire damage. Thus, the Wildfire spell gains a bonus to its damage, which happens each time somebody enters a Wildfire square. Thus, they take more than 1 damage for each square.

Supporting that increasing the per-square damage is even possible is the Heightened effect of Wildfire itself:

> Heightened (+2) Increase the damage and persistent damage by 1.

"The damage" *is* the per-square damage so when Burn It! similarly increases the damage, it is increasing this per-square damage.

Comment: Burn It! also increases the persistent damage ("You also gain a +1 status bonus to any persistent fire damage you deal."), so this is a _very_ good combo.

Comment: @ESCE Yeah I'm actually unsure why it mentions that, do damage increasing effects not impact persistent damage? Is the persistent damage not also "fire damage from a spell"? Maybe it's just reiterating

Comment: Well, notably, Burn It! doesn't mention that the +1 bonus to persistent damage increases with level ("You also..."), so I'm fairly sure that somewhere bonuses like this one (and [Dangerous Sorcery](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=603)) are not supposed to apply to persistent damage. See this question: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/179874/how-exactly-does-burn-it-and-similar-effects-affect-splash-and-ongoing-damage/179879#179879 (specifically, the distinction between persistent damage and its originating effect)