# How does Unleash Psyche interact with amped Produce Flame?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

A level 1 Oscillating Wave Psychic uses Unleash Psyche. He then casts an amped Produce Flame as a ranged attack.

1. On a success, how much damage does the target of Produce Flame take?
2. On a critical success, how much persistent fire damage would the target take?
3. How much damage do other creatures only hit by the splash take?

Comment: What exactly is the confusion here? That might allow us to make a more directly helpful answer, by addressing any points of confusion in how we arrive at the results.

Comment: How the three different damage components (normal, splash, persistent) interact with the bonus damage from Unleash Psyche. @Ifusaso covered the different cases well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Damage

Oscillating Wave Amped Produce Flame says

> The initial damage changes to 1d10 fire damage (not adding your ability modifier) plus 1 fire splash damage. When using amped produce flame as a melee attack, increase the damage dice of the initial damage from d10s to d12s.[...]
> **Amp Heightened (+1)** Instead of using produce flame's normal heightened entry, the initial damage increases by 1d10 (1d12 for melee) and the splash damage increases by 1.

For a ranged attack, you are dealing 1d10 damage and 1 splash damage at level 1-2. Unleash Psyche gives

> When you cast a damaging spell, you gain a status bonus to its damage equal to double the spell's level. This applies only to spells that don't have a duration and that you cast using psychic spellcasting.

Amped Cantrips meet these requirements, so you gain +2 status bonus to the damage and splash. The status bonus doesn't stack across damage types, so you can summarize that the primary target takes +2 splash damage (assuming they don't negate the splash somehow, in which case they would still take 1d10+2). Additionally, on a critical hit, the status bonus would be doubled for the primary target (but not the splash damage) because they would take the +4 status bonus damage on the 1d10, causing that to be the larger bonus.

**1d10 + 3 splash**
Critical: **(1d10+2)x2 + 1 splash to the primary target and 3 splash to adjacent targets**

Note that, per the rules for the [Splash](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=150) trait, the 3 damage will be taken even on a Failure (but not a Critical Failure) of the attack roll.

### Persistent Damage

Unleash Psyche doesn't affect the persistent damage because the persistent damage is a Condition imposed on the target. Persistent damage remains

**1d4**

### Splash Damage

Splash damage *is* affected by the status bonus, so all adjacent creatures will take

**3 splash**

---

For further clarification regarding my last argument in the damage section and how the Persistent Damage (doesn't) interact, see [my answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/179879/28326) about the effect of the Burn It! Goblin Feat.

Comment: Regarding "assuming they don't avoid it somehow, in which case they would still take 1d10+2". The "it" here refers to the splash, right? The bonus damage applies to both the normal damage and the splash, but doesn't stack with itself if both are applied.

Comment: Exactly, I'll see if I can word it a bit more clearly but that's correct

Answer (score 0):

### Each Damage Roll Gets the Bonus

[Unleash Psyche](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=1222) gives damaging spells a status bonus to damage equal to double the spell's level, while an amped *[produce flame](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=236)* from a pyschic of [The Oscillating Wave](https://2e.aonprd.com/ConsciousMinds.aspx?ID=3) conscious mind changes the initial damage:

> **Amp** You project pure heat that causes a target to combust. The initial damage changes to 1d10 fire damage (not adding your ability modifier) plus 1 fire splash damage...
>
> **Amp Heightened (+1)** Instead of using *produce flame's* normal heightened entry, the initial damage increases by 1d10 (1d12 for melee) and the splash damage increases by 1. The persistent fire damage on a critical hit increases by 1d4.

### Bonus to Damage

> As with checks, you might add circumstance, status, or item bonuses to your damage rolls, but if you have multiple bonuses of the same type, you add only the highest bonus of that type.

Status bonuses [don't stack](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=22), but the bonus here is instead applying to three different damage rolls. If some other effect was granting a status bonus to damage like the goblin feat [Burn It!](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=38) then only the largest bonus would apply.

> When making a damage roll, you take the following steps, explained in detail below.
>
> - Roll the dice indicated by the weapon, unarmed attack, or spell, and apply the modifiers, bonuses, and penalties that apply to the result of the roll.
> - Determine the damage type.
> - Apply the target’s immunities, weaknesses, and resistances to the damage.
> - If any damage remains, reduce the target’s Hit Points by that amount.

[Each damage type has its own damage roll](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/205778/72765), and because Unleash Psyche doesn't give a bonus to any particular type of damage, all [damage types](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=340) of the spell would gain the status bonus, including the fire damage, splash fire damage, and persistent fire damage.

> Add splash damage together with the initial damage against the target before applying the target's resistance or weakness.

[Splash](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=704) damage has an exception to be added to the initial damage before applying resistances and weaknesses of the target in step 3 of [dealing damage](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=335), but this happens after both damage rolls have have already been made in their respective step 1s and the damage types have been determined in their step 2s.

As each damage roll being independently calculated, the status bonus from Unleash Psyche still applies to each damage type without being limited to one bonus for the amount dealt to the target.

### Critical Hits

Splash damage isn't modified by critical hits, but it does apply to the target and any adjacent creatures even on a failure.

> Benefits you gain specifically from a critical hit, like the *flaming* weapon rune’s persistent fire damage or the extra damage die from the fatal weapon trait, aren’t doubled.

Persistent damage normally doubles on a critical hit as damage (clarified in [later printings](https://paizo.com/pathfinder/faq) of the *Core Rulebook*), but damage [doesn't double](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=339) if it's only dealt on a critical hit. For *produce flame*, this means the persistent damage isn't doubled.

### Damage

For an amped 1st level *produce flame*:

- **Failure**: 3 fire splash damage
- **Success**: 1d10 + 2 fire damage plus 3 fire splash damage
- **Critical Success**: 2 * (1d10 + 2) fire damage plus 3 fire splash damage plus 1d4 + 2 persistent fire damage

Or more generally with LV = spell level:

- **Failure**: LV + LV * 2 fire splash damage
- **Success**: LVd10 + LV * 2 fire damage plus LV + LV * 2 fire splash damage
- **Critical Success**: 2 * (LVd10 + LV * 2) fire damage plus LV + LV * 2 fire splash damage plus LVd4 + LV * 2 persistent fire damage

Comment: Good catch on the critical effect modifying things. Are you saying Ability modifier is added for MOD? Or is that the Status Bonus? If ability modifier, I'm curious your take on the parenthesis in the Amp text. I still disagree about it being added to all damage types, of course, but it's fair for the community to be exposed to both sides.

Comment: Splash and the main damage is the same instance against the primary target, that is why it only triggers weaknesses and resistances only once. Then it receives the status bonus only once too (or twice, but it does not stack)

Comment: @András They are added together into the same instance of damage for determining weaknesses and resistances, but bonuses and penalties to the damage rolls happen before that when actually rolling the damages.