# Does a spell that deals persistent damage allow you to use the Energy Fusion metamagic feat?

Tags: spells, feats, pathfinder-2e, metamagic

[Blistering Invective](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=674) deals persistent damage:

> Your words **deal** 2d6 persistent fire **damage**, and the target must attempt a Will save.

[Energy Fusion](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1821) adds a different damage type to a spell that deals energy damage:

> If the next action you use is to Cast a Spell that **deals** acid, cold, electricity, fire, or sonic **damage**, select a non-cantrip spell in your spell repertoire that deals a different type of energy damage from that list, and expend an additional spell slot of the same level as this secondary spell.

Do these work together?

Comment: Related: "[How exactly does Burn It! (and similar effects) affect splash and ongoing damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/179874)" and "[Burn it and alchemist fire persistent damage](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/129845)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No, but...

**No,** as I explain in my [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/179879/28326) to the question Medix2 linked in comments, applying the same (seemingly accurate) ruling suggests that the combination does not work.

Specifically, persistent damage is "dealt by" a [Condition](https://2e.aonprd.com/Conditions.aspx?ID=29), not the character that inflicted the Condition. By extension, the spell is not "dealing" damage in the sense that Energy Fusion implies; it would be different if *blistering invective* had a duration over which it did damage instead of being the Condition persistent damage.

**But...** this is something a GM could easily rule the other way on. It will increase the effectiveness of Energy Fusion a bit (I believe the "expected" duration on persistent damage is approximately three ticks) at the 'cost' of using less up-front damage. A 4th level *blistering invective* does 4d6 damage to 3 creatures whereas a 4th level *fireball* (ye olde go-to for spell damage comparison) does 8d6 to everything in a 20ft radius. It takes a second round for BI to catch up in damage assuming *fireball* only hit 3 targets.

However, GM's should take care as there are other spells that trigger persistent damage, and it's possible that, depending on group composition and enemy types/density/etc., adding sometimes 2-4+ times the bonus damage from Energy Fusion (in addition to the non-damage effects of such spells) could cause issues with spells hitting well above their weight.